# Why can Serde not derive Deserialize for a struct containing only a &Path?

Tags: rust, serde

I tried to derive `serde::Deserialize` for a struct containing a reference to a `Path`. This yielded an error message which doesn't occur if you replace `&'a Path` with `&'a str`. What causes the different behaviours of `#[derive(Deserialize)]`?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ad204f38b8bbe8910c58a003cf31228a)

````rust
#!/bin/cargo script
//! ```cargo
//! [dependencies]
//! serde_derive="1.0"
//! serde="1.0"
//! ```

extern crate serde_derive;

use serde_derive::*;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct A<'a> {
    a: &'a std::path::Path,
    //a: &'a str,
}

fn main() {}
````

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'de` due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/main.rs:7:5
  |
7 |     a: &'a std::path::Path,
  |     ^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime 'de as defined on the impl at 5:10...
 --> src/main.rs:5:10
  |
5 | #[derive(Deserialize)]
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
          expected _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_A::_serde::de::SeqAccess<'_>
             found _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_A::_serde::de::SeqAccess<'de>
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 6:10...
 --> src/main.rs:6:10
  |
6 | struct A<'a> {
  |          ^^
  = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
          expected _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_A::_serde::Deserialize<'_>
             found _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_A::_serde::Deserialize<'_>

error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'de` due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/main.rs:7:5
  |
7 |     a: &'a std::path::Path,
  |     ^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime 'de as defined on the impl at 5:10...
 --> src/main.rs:5:10
  |
5 | #[derive(Deserialize)]
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
          expected _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_A::_serde::de::MapAccess<'_>
             found _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_A::_serde::de::MapAccess<'de>
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 6:10...
 --> src/main.rs:6:10
  |
6 | struct A<'a> {
  |          ^^
  = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
          expected _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_A::_serde::Deserialize<'_>
             found _IMPL_DESERIALIZE_FOR_A::_serde::Deserialize<'_>
```

Strangely enough, the code compiles if the struct contains both fields `_a: &'a Path` and `_b: &'a str`... At this point I think this is a [bug](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1542).

Comment: Use `a: PathBuf`

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios thanks for the recommendation, but I can afford to be stubborn on this one :)

Comment: Hm, I looked at the `impl`s of `Deserialize` for `&'a str` and `&'a Path` and everything looks the same for both cases except for a type conversion via `AsRef`, but that's in the body of `PathVisitor` and that should long be typechecked when this error occurs. It looks like it might even be a bug in the lifetime inference.

Comment: @JanHudec thanks for investigating this. I filed a bug report, just in case. A faulty lifetime inference engine does sound nasty, so I hope it's not that ^^

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add an attribute to the field: `#[serde(borrow)]`. That will indicate to serde that it should be borrowing the value. You must provide this attribute for every borrow except for `&str` and `&[u8]`.

Source: https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html#borrowing-data-in-a-derived-impl