# Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'de` due to conflicting requirements

Tags: rust, lifetime

Take the following code snippet (has to be run in cargo, so you can add the `serde` feature to `num-bigint`):

```rust
use num_bigint::BigInt;
use serde_derive::Deserialize;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Trade<'a> {
    pub id: &'a str,
    pub price: BigInt,
    pub quantity: BigInt,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct TradeTable<'a> {
    pub trades: Vec<Trade<'a>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut ether_trades: Vec<Trade> = Vec::new();
    ether_trades.push(Trade {
        id: "#1",
        price: BigInt::from(100),
        quantity: BigInt::from(2)
    });

    let mut trades: HashMap<&str, Vec<Trade>> = HashMap::new();
    trades.insert("ETH", ether_trades);
    println!("trades: {}", trades);
}
```

It yields this error when compiling:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'de` due to conflicting requirements
```

And this note:

```
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'de` as defined on the impl at 34:17...
```

Now, I understand that I need to make `'a` live shorter than `'de`, but how can I do that? I don't know where the `'de` lifetime is defined. I tried to use a colon like this:

```rust
'de: 'a
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: Since the lifetime `'de` doesn't appear in the code you posted, there must be an important piece of code missing. Please add the relevant code, and show the full compiler error.

Comment: @Aloso that's the thing, I don't know where `'de` is. It doesn't appear in my source code either.

Comment: The error message should tell you the **file, line number and column** (e.g. `--> src/main.rs:29:18`)

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, the error is concerning this line: `pub trades: Vec<Trade<'a>>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can Serde not derive Deserialize for a struct containing only a &Path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56394620/why-can-serde-not-derive-deserialize-for-a-struct-containing-only-a-path)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check [that one](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html#borrowing-data-in-a-derived-impl)

TL;DR

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct TradeTable<'a> {
    #[serde(borrow)]
    pub trades: Vec<Trade<'a>>,
}
```

Comment: If [you suspect something is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60794121/cannot-infer-an-appropriate-lifetime-for-lifetime-parameter-de-due-to-conflic?noredirect=1#comment107604126_60794121), please do not answer it. Instead, vote to close it as a duplicate.